# Submit Form based on dataverse table with Polymorphic field owner

Tags: polymorphism, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

I've created a form based on a dataverse table with *User/Team ownership*.

In such table only 3 fields are required:

- ID
- Status
- Owner

When adding those 3 field to the form I can see values for the first 2, not for the Owner field.

Trying to submit the form (after modifying an existing record) I get a generic failure message.

```
An entry is required or has an invalid value. Please correct and try again
```

I have the suspect that the form doesn't provide data for updating the Owner field, and this led me to study those **Polymorphic fields**.

After reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-references), [that](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Change-owner-of-activity-in-canvas-apps/m-p/434593#M128745) and [another post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/SubmitForm-function-not-working/td-p/772377), I understood how to show the Owner of this field in the form datacard (although this was not my goal). But I'm still having problem updating that field.

so **my question is**, if a record already has an owner, do I still need to Update it? how can I do that? do I need to use Patch or can I write it in the **Update** property to make it work along with **SubmitForm(...)**?

In this case for me the **owner** should be automatically picked up based on **User().Email**.

**Bonus question**, when creating a new record in this table, will I also have to generate the ID or dataverse will still take care of it?
on the same topic, will I have to figure out how to provide an "Active" value for the Status field too?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in the end, sharing here should anybody need it in the future:

**You don't need to update the field**, if not included in the loaded fields of the form, Dataverse in the background will take care of adding owner, status, and the ID (if properly set on Dataverse side). **So simply exclude those fields from the form and the system will take care of them.**

> But at first I didn't have those fields and yet could not save the
> form.

It was in the end because of another field, a **lookup field that describes the relationship** with another table. Once I took care of filling out that field automatically in the background (not visible data-card), it worked properly, but **those 3 fields were still included**, hence the error that I was encountering.

This also answer to my "**bonus question**", yes, PowerApps and Dataverse **take care of filling out those fields also when creating a new item.**

Comment: Correct,  those are "Audit" and "Owner" fields, there is also createdon/by modifiedOn/by and an OnBehalfOf Owner when the record is created/updated via impersonation.